# QMap Serialization in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a 2 classes: `valueNode` and `keyNode`. Both of these classes have 2 private members. Now I create a `QMap< keyNode , valueNode >`. for this I override `operator<()`. I want to serialize this QMap but I don't know how.

Comment: why can't you? what problem are you having? what compiler errors?

Answer (score 7):

```
QMap<QString, QString> map;
map.insert("Hello", " World!");

QByteArray data;
QDataStream * stream = new QDataStream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

(*stream) << map;
delete stream;

// Now QByteArray should have the map as serialized data.
```

This should work.

You might wonder about the *new* and *delete* madness, but there is a reason: there is no way to flush the data from the stream to the bytearray, except by deconstructing the stream. Or maybe there is, give me a comment if I'm wrong.

*Edit:*

Oh yeah, forgot one thing.

You need to make these functions:

```
QDataStream & operator << (QDataStream & out, const MyClass & object);
QDataStream & operator >> (QDataStream & in, MyClass & object);
```

Introduce them in the headers of your classes and implement in the cpp file of that class.

```
// MyClass.h

MyClass
{
    ...
};

QDataStream & operator << ...
QDataStream & operator >> ...
```

Note that it must be a global function and **not** a member function.

Note that you must create a pair for each of your classes.

Comment: Instead of new and delete, you can just scope the QDataStream on the stack by adding `{` before the line where you `new` and `}` instead of the line where you `delete`

Comment: @Troyseph You are correct. I wanted to put a lot of emphasis on the fact, that's why I used something that is immediately clear to anyone. I felt that new / delete is better than scoping it out, not everyone is as observant as you.

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a QVariant which you can then use a QDataStream to read/write it.

Comment: QMap is a native Qt type, it can be serialized without a need for an intermediate QVariant.